# (Big issue) Blog is Getting Down Each day.. what should i do.?

Tags: plugins, themes, hosting

I am using KnownHost Hosting (SSD-VPS-3 Plan) and My Site is getting about 50K pageviews each day ( according to Jetpack plugin )

Sometimes my Site is getting Down 3-4 time each ( each time for 10-20 minutes Down ) So I ask KnownHost Team to tell me what's the Problem.?

So Reply comes up from KnownHost is:-

That's really primarily a matter of improving the efficiency of your site's code; the VPS already has access to CPU resources comparable to our larger dedicated server packages. I suggest reading https://codex.wordpress.org/High_Traffic_Tips_For_WordPress for tips on improving the efficiency of WordPress sites, as the total traffic to that site is actually fairly unremarkable (~28K Apache requests in the last hour; I've seen other WordPress sites on comparable packages handle hundreds of thousands of requests per hour). You're already using the DSO PHP handler with Zend Opcache and nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache, which are the main suggestions I'd make as far as server configuration goes; you may be able to get some additional performance improvement by replacing Apache with Litespeed, but that's not going to be a massive improvement over what you've already got.

So Friends Please tell me what should I do.? This is Very issue for me and I want to Fix this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: There are thousands of reasons for a site to load slow or increase server loads. First suggestion would be disabling all the plugins and check if the site has any issues without those plugins. Then re-activate one by one to find out the plugin. What are your server load at pick? Are there any php execution timeout errors in server log?

Comment: This is most probably caused by plugins. How many do you use?

Comment: No Error...Browser do not load website.. I am unable to add my Plugins list here ( I think here is Text limitation ) can you please check here. http://ask.shoutmeloud.com/t/big-issue-blog-is-getting-down-each-day-what-should-i-do/6957/6